# Load binary image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I would like to display image downloaded from specific URL using jquery ajax. How can I achieve it? (without setting image .src) I also need to rotate and scale that image.

Comment: You could do it using Data:url's. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL. Check the information under **Embedding an image via data:url** at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: Could you explain a little bit deeper why you need such approach? Remember that jQuery runs "beside" HTML, soon or later you will depend on the tag IMG or CSS's background-image to show the image.

Comment: it's flickering when I change .src

Comment: Why not hide the img, replace it with src, then fade it in?

Comment: That seems fair. But can you edit image using Javascript? For example rescale/rotate or draw on it?

Comment: You can use the javascript `Image` object to load and manipulate images without them being part of the DOM. (Well to "manipulate" you'll need to use a canvas, but you can source a canvas from an `Image` same as from an `img`)

Comment: "it's flickering when I change .src" In that case your question should be why is the image flickering, and then post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<canvas>` and populate it with an image. When loaded, the image can be rotated, scaled, drawn on, etc.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)'s a good tutorial that does exactly what you need.

In order to get this running in IE, I suggest using [ExplorerCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the flicking of the image, you could first `hide` the image before loading and `show` it after the `src` have been loaded.

```
$('<img>').hide().attr('src', 'img_url').onload(function() {$(this).show()});
```

To rotate or do other mutation on the image, I sugguest use the [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/hsl/) Library which is compatible across browsers.